# Можно ли вместо автора той-иной песни ссылку на исполнителя давать?

Tags: оформление-текста

Можно ли вместо автора той-иной песни ссылку на исполнителя давать?

«Ты и я одна компания...» (Боярский. Песенка кота и пирата).

«Если б кто-то нам сказал вчера, что...» (ВИА Красные маки. Всё, что было).